# Ignoring escape characters in perl

Tags: perl

```
my %result = "\\path\tfolder\file.txt";
```

How can I ignore the \t escape sequence without prepending a '\'. Is there something like:

```
my %result = r"\\path\tfolder\file.txt";
```

The above doesn't work.

Comment: You should always use `use strict; use warnings;` in your scripts. If you had, you would have been given the warning `Odd number of elements in hash assignment at ...` You should also be aware that saying "it doesn't work" is a very, very poor way to describe a programming problem.

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes process two escape sequences: `\\` and `\'`, so you would have to double the leading double-backslash but not the others:

```
my $result = '\\\\server\toppath\files';
```

To get what you want, you could use a here-document at the cost of some syntactic bulk.

```
chomp(my $result = <<'EOPath');
\\server\toppath\files
EOPath
```

Note the change of sigil from `%` to `$` because a string is a scalar, and hashes are for associations.

Comment: $a = '\\server\toppath\files';
print $a;

Comment: @Nemo How to correct what? You seem to be thinking that we can read your mind. That path seems to print correctly, and it certainly does not print just "\server".